# Error uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker (NameError) en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cuando intento crear algo me salta el siguiente error en la consola:

> `marcom@marcom-Lenovo-G40-80:~/Escritorio/APPI$ rails g controller asd
>   /home/marcom/Escritorio/APPI/config/environments/development.rb:53:in`
>   block in ': uninitialized constant
>   ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker (NameError)   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in
>   `instance_eval'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in`
>   configure'   from
>   /home/marcom/Escritorio/APPI/config/environments/development.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in
>   `each'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in`
>   block in '     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`
>   block in tsort_each'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in
>   `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in`
>   block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in`
>   block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
>   `each'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`
>   tsort_each_child'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in
>   `call'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in
>   `block in each_strongly_connected_component'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   each'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   `call'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in
>   `tsort_each'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in`
>   tsort_each'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `run_initializers'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`
>   initialize!'     from
>   /home/marcom/Escritorio/APPI/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in`
>   require'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in
>   `preload'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in`
>   serve'   from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in
>   `block in run'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`
>   loop'    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in
>   `run'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /home/marcom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from -e:1:in `'

Comment: ¿Que versión de rails estás usando?

Comment: inicializaste rails en el directorio algo como `rails new nombre_app`?

Comment: Tenia la 5.0.1 pero la cambie a la 4.2.7

Comment: Si, si cree la aplicacion, segun leí en algunos lugares es por el tema de la version, intenté usar rails <_version_> new <Nombre> pero aun asi me tira en la version 5.0.1 y debo forzarla a la 4.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` fue introducido en Rails 5. Si bajaste de versión tan solo cambiando de versión de rails en tu `Gemfile`, claramente te va a causar problemas, porque los archivos de configuración siguen hechos para rails 5.
Tienes dos opciones, la primera es comentar/borrar la línea de configuración que te está causando el problema:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

La segunda es que simplemente inicies desde cero un proyecto rails con `rails new tuproyecto`. Fíjate que versión de rails estás usando con `rails -v` y asegúrate que estas creando el proyecto con la versión 5.x.

Personalmente te recomendaría, sobretodo si estás recién comenzando tu proyecto, la segunda opción, ya que el comentar dicha línea no te asegura que puedas tener otro tipo de problemas más adelante por nuevas características introducidas en rails 5.x y que no estén en 4.x

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente era un problema por la versión, inicié un proyecto desde cero con otra versión y me funcionó.