# Error uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Obtengo este error al ejecutar el comando

> rails generate model

De acuerdo con [éste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47469/error-uninitialized-constant-activesupporteventedfileupdatechecker-nameerror) articulo el error se debe a que EventedFileUpdateChecker fue introducido en la versión 5 de Rails, sin embargo el proyecto fue creado usando Rails 5 y así aparece en el Gemfile, además, al ejecutar el comando rails -v obtengo

> Rails 5.0.0.1

Cabe mencionar que al intentar ejecutar el comando

> rails generate *cualquier_cosa*

en un proyecto nuevo obtengo el mismo error

source 'https://rubygems.org'

Adjunto mi Gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '= 5.0.0.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11.4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'figaro'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Bootstrap gem
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-select-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'

# Reset css
gem 'normalize-rails'

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable", '<= 0.8.5'

# Internationalization
gem 'rails-i18n'

# Runtime developer console
gem 'pry'

# Read cvs or excel files
gem 'roo'
gem "iconv"

# Generate Excel files
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'axlsx_rails'

# JQuery validates
gem "jquery-validation-rails"

#Generates documentation
gem 'apipie-rails'

gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.14.5'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'

# Responsive tables
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-johnpolacek--stacktable.js'
end

# Paginate
# gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Si comento la linea

```
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

A veces se queda atorado y me toca cerrar la consola y a veces la consola imprime esto:

> Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed 
>   gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
>   Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:47: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:51: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   -e: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Y esa versión `5.0.0.1` ¿es efectivamente la que te aparece en tu Gemfile? ¿podrías agregar el error completo? ¿has probado con la primera solución de la respuesta que adjuntaste?

Comment: puedes compartir tu gemfile?

Comment: 1. Esa es la versión que tengo en el Gemfile, la 5.0.0.1

Comment: 3. La primera solución que se propone en mi adjunto dice que comente una linea, al comentarla sale otro error

Answer (score 0):

Si estás empezando un proyecto desde cero, deberías actualizar tu versión de rails, a menos que tengas una razón de peso para comenzar un nuevo proyecto con `5.0.0.1` (lo dudo).
Esa es una versión bastante preliminar de `5.x` y puede que tenga problemas, aparte de fallas de seguridad, bugs, entre otros, que lo más seguro ya hayan sido resuelto en nuevas versiones.

Comment: El proyecto fue creado en la versión 5.0.0.1 hace ya un tiempo, el error al que hago referencia apareció de repente, sospecho que fue al actualizar a la versión de rails a 5.7.1, sin embargo retroceder a la versión 5.0.0.1 no arregla el problema.